# Computing an expection without brute force

Tags: probability

Let $\xi,\eta$ be i.i.d random variables with distribution function $F(x)$. $E|\xi| < \infty$, prove that
$$ E|\xi + \eta| - E|\xi - \eta| = \int_{0}^{\infty} \left( 1 - F(t)-F(-t) \right)^2 \mathrm{d}t $$

I can do this by brute force(by partition of the plane, and compute each integral), but is there a more elegant way to solve it?